# Sql indentation in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, indentation

Folks, is there a tool to format/indent SQL Server queries in query window ?

Comment: There should be same option like we have in visual studio built in.
Ctrl + K + D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 to JackM.

Just add a mention for some other (not free) tools available from Red Gate, depending on exact requirements.

[SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm)
[SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm)

Might be something you'd be interested in.

Comment: SQL Refactor -> Layout Sql seems more like it...

Answer (score 8):

With [Apex SQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx), you can specify your formatting preferences and reformat selected code or the entire window at any time using a keyboard shortcut. There's a free version.

[image: ApexSQL Refactor]

Answer (score 2):

[Format code in SQL Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174157.aspx)

Comment: Not quite like the way i wanted but nevertheless useful.

Answer (score 2):

Older question which has much more activity and more answers: [SQL Formatter for SQL Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401928/sql-formatter-for-sql-management-studio)

My contributon to this mess is [Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter](http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx) / http://poorsql.com - free, open-source, does bulk formatting from command-line, SSMS plugin, etc, and (in theory) handles all SQL syntax up to SQL Server 2008 (R2).