# Format SQL statements in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> (format document) in SQL Server Management Studio. It gives the message

> The key combination (key, key) is bound to command(command) which is not currently available.

I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>, and that didn't work either.

Is there any update or fix that I need to install for that?

Comment: Did you mean SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is nothing to fix - SQL Server Management Studio is not Visual Studio and does not contain a SQL pretty printer.

In other words, SSMS does not have a document formatting option out of the box.

See the answers to [SQL Formatter for SQL Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401928/sql-formatter-for-sql-management-studio) for options.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this, Finally found this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and it worked for me.
But you need to have SQL Prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Try CTRL+Y it will work.
first select all the code to which you want to do formatting then press CTRL+Y.