# SQL - way to align the code in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Are there any provision available in SSMS to align the SQL code. Arrange the SQL SP scripts in a readable format. Whenever I align the SP scripts and run a ALTER PROC. The scripts got misaligned when i retrieve the SP code using sp_helptext.

Like how we align the C# OR .aspx codes in Visual Studio using the shortcut key Ctrl +KD, Any option available in SSMS?

Answer (score 2):

- Redgate: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/
- ApexSQL: http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx
- SQL Pretty Pinter: http://www.dpriver.com/products/sqlpp/ssms_index.php

There's a bunch -- some free, some not.  Google 'SQL Format SSMS'...

Answer (score 1):

You can try SQL Prompt. However it is not free.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/

[image]

You might also want to look at this answer -

[SQL Formatter for SQL Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401928/sql-formatter-for-sql-management-studio)

Answer (score 0):

There is auto-formatting function available in SSMS. Please refer book online topic on [Manage Code Formatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174157.aspx).

Comment: When I try to enable it using the following steps, it resets back. I am not able to select option 'smart'   To automatically indent all of your code
On the Tools menu, click Options.
Click Text Editor.
Click All Languages.
Click Tabs.
Click Smart.

Comment: This is the basic free stuff that comes with SSMS. Even though the tools->options dialog box shows it as reset, the settings should still work. At least, that has been my experience. Your modified settings file is saved in the folder `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Settings`, and that is used to load your personalized settings.  If you want to pay or your IT allows third party freebies, there are several out there.