# Does the Poor Mans T-SQL formatting add-in for Management Studio 2012 work in Management Studio 2014?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

Does the Poor Mans T-SQL formatting add-in for Management Studio 2012 work in Management Studio 2014?

In SSMS 2012, if I go to tools, it showed up in the list. In SSMS 2014, it doesn't.

I tried to run the installer again, and it gave me options to repair or uninstall. I had the formatter installed prior to installing 2014.

EDIT: [The tool is available here.](http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx)

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the tool you are asking about?

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't work. The add-in mechanism changed slightly between versions, but really, you should be contacting the add-in's authors to find this out.

Comment: Is there a rich man's SQL formatter?

Comment: @popovitsj I would not know. Please ask someone who is lol

Comment: Did you uninstall and then reinstall?

Comment: Did you re-install management studio, or re-install the formatter add-in? I would expect the latter to help, but not the former.

Comment: @popovitsj Yeah, it's called Red Gate

Comment: Might be of interest to people that the free tool SSMSBoost has this feature and more http://www.ssmsboost.com/

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Create the folder

```
%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\12.0\Addins\
```

if it does not exist. Then just copy the file from:

```
%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Addins\PoorMansTSqlFormatterSSMSAddIn.AddIn
```

to

```
%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\12.0\Addins\PoorMansTSqlFormatterSSMSAddIn.AddIn
```

Comment: Confirmed that this also works with SQL 2016 CTP.  You just need to add the folder as "13.0".

Comment: This works, just make sure to follow path names exactly. I now get a Format Sql menu under Tools.

Comment: Seems to be broken in the latest 2016 version with updated visual studio shell running in isolated mode. Anyone get it to work.

Comment: I guess issue is that SSMS 2016 no longer supports addings, everything is a extension now. Code needs to be updated to support SSMS 2016 and upwards.

Comment: For SSMS 2017 Adding folder 14.0 and copying the add-in doesn't  work for me

Comment: Support added for SSMS 2014 (official / no hack required), 2016 and 17. Download at: http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx

Answer (score 21):

UPDATE: more than three years later, this support has finally been added.

Download page is still http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx for now.

Comment: Your tool is awesome. Please do let me know when it's updated!

Comment: Note: this is open source so if you have the time to make the simple change you can contribute. Would be nice for 2016 as well. http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx#Contributing_11

Comment: FYI - Currently trying to get this working in SSMS 17.1... hold my beer.

Comment: @CaptainMarvel sorry about the wait, this is finally done (including SSMS 17) - download in the usual place.

Comment: When I execute PoorMansTSqlFormatterSSMSPackage.Setup.1.6.16.msi for SSMS v18.1 then I do not see PoorMansTSqlFormatterSSMSAddIn.dll anywhere in my system.I copy this dll from another system .Do dll version matter ? Why dll not getting downloaded.

Comment: There seems to be an issue for SSMS 18.8, one suggestion [on youTube](https://youtu.be/jcAsmND1C2I) suggested installing VS Isolated Shell which works.
The msi installer places the pkgdef file under ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Extensions``` could it just be missing an *extension.vsixmanifest* file? 
(as another similar extension has w/o needing the Iso Shell)

Answer (score 7):

With the permission of the PoorMans Formatter developer we have integrated it in our add-in "[SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com)". Recent version of SSMSBoost supports SSMS 2014, so you can use it to use Poor Man's formatter features. We have already developerd our own formatting engine, but have left "Poor Man's formatter" for backward compatibility, for those users, used to it. You will find it in formatter-styles drop-down as "Old fashioned formatting style".

Comment: I switched to using this plugin because the poor man's SQL formatter hasn't updated it's code base to work with 2014

Comment: Tried this, but could not find a way to format the sql code, no menu option.

Comment: After installing SSMSBoost, you see it's toolbar. It contains "Format SQL" button. Near this button there is a drop-down where you can choose formatting engine and templates. If you have problems - write us to support@ssmsboost email

Comment: This tool has it all - I'm very impressed. admitally; I haven't seen the price yet.

Answer (score 2):

No, it has not been updated yet.

As of 2014-04-25 the most recent built is from 2013-10-23, version 1.5.3.

http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx#Latest_Changes_6

Edit:

Since I hadn't installed the plug-in on my new machine with 2014 I went a head and tried. It does not work on my fresh install, but does still on the side-by-side 2012.

Comment: @Hoppe sorry for the confusion. My typing is lousy. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

With SSMS 18.10 I successfully got Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter working applying the proposed fix from https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/234#issuecomment-1264508689

Add the following (missing) tags to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe.config

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: not work from me, I using ssms v18.3.1 (15.0.18183.0), I tried follow the instruction (install PoorMansTSqlFormatterSSMSAddIn.Setup.1.6.10.msi & 1.6.16.msi) also add Addins\PoorMansTSqlFormatterSSMSAddIn.AddIn on 11 & 12. but got nothing on my tools. Did I miss something?