# Does the Poor Man's T-SQL formatting add-in for Management Studio 2012 work in Management Studio 2016?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-addin

Basically the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303026/does-the-poor-mans-t-sql-formatting-add-in-for-management-studio-2012-work-in-ma) but now for SSMS 2016.

I've installed SSMS 2016 RC3 (alongside SSMS2012 & SSMS2014). I also installed Poor Man's formatter and copied the 11.0 folder as 12.0 and 13.0. When launching SSMS2014 I have the Tools > Format T-SQL Code menu-option. Which I don't have in SSMS106. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3):

Since RC2, they've moved to using Visual Studio 2015 shell for it. Plugin authors will need to update their plugins to support the newer APIs. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/134208

Also, take a look at [ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx). It's free and supports code-formatting as well. <del>At this time of writing, it currently doesn't work with SSMS2016 RC2 and above though</del>. It also now supports SSMS 2016.

Comment: ApexSQL Refactor looks good on first glance, but surprised me by taking over the Ctrl-Shift-B keyboard shortcut that I constantly use to rebuild the solution.

Comment: Just curious, what do you build in SSMS?

Comment: My apologies. I've installed ApexSQL into both SSMS 2016 and Visual Studio 2015, and I struck the Ctrl-Shift-B issue in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

This support was finally added today. Download the new SSMS Extension at http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a try with it