# Renaming/ Refactoring in Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

Are there any free tools/ plug ins for simple refactoring/ code formatting in SQL Server Management Studio?

Really the only things I'm looking for are indentation, and variable renaming.

For example, in Visual Studio, I can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and it will pop up a window allowing me to rename the variable the cursor is on.

Similarly, I can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and VS will auto indent my code to the appropriate levels.

If there was a way I could perform those two functions in SSMS, that would be great.

Either SQL Server 2008 or 2012 would be fine.

Comment: RedGate SQL Tools are not free. You can get a free trail though.

Comment: For formatting refer to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401928/sql-formatter-for-sql-management-studio

Comment: I'd say that because variables are really only used within the scope of a single procedure find and replace is your friend here. Can't speak to the indentation. See also [sp_helpText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx)

Comment: Doesn't SSDT have a pretty smart refactor?