# Poor mans T-SQL formatting add-in "Format T-SQL Code" option disabled in SQL Server Management Studio v18.5

Tags: ssms-18

Refer to the following screenshot:

[image]

In the previous versions of SQL Server Management Studio, it was working perfectly. I am using Windows 10 on a desktop PC.

Appreciate any help for this :)

Comment: It's probably worth to mention in the body of the question that you are using [Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197517/11683).

Comment: I found the answer: Need to download and install Visual studio 2015 isolated shell from the following link:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Edit ssms.exe.config
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE

In `<assemblyBinding>` Add

```
<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/> 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0-15.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/> 
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Using your solution there is no need to install Visual Studio 2015 Isolated Shell. thanks

Comment: Life saver! I used this to fix SSMS v19.0.2.

Comment: Save my life too! SSMS V18.12.1

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I honestly struggle to write SQL correctly without Poor Man's SQL Formatter. It helps find stray brackets for one thing.

Answer (score 19):

For the versions of the plugin that supports SSMS 2014-2018, PoorMan's T-SQL Formatter requires the Visual Studio 2015 Isolated Shell installed in order to work.
It can be downloaded from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/). After installing it, the option will be made available.

[image: The formatter is now enabled.]

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja Because of the question had no answer (in the way SO works), I added one to it based on your comment after trying it by myself, so it's easier for people to see the solution ;)