# Are there any additional installation requirements to use Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter in SQL Server Management Studio? Because I am unable to access it

Tags: tooltip, ssms

I have installed poor man's SQL formatter in SSMS v18.9.1

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Poor mans T-SQL formatting add-in "Format T-SQL Code" option disabled in SQL Server Management Studio v18.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313632/poor-mans-t-sql-formatting-add-in-format-t-sql-code-option-disabled-in-sql-ser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [issue #265 in the Github repository](https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/265) and [link to a fix in issue #244](https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/244#issuecomment-729047935).

```
Edit ssms.exe.config
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE

In <assemblyBinding> Add

<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0-15.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/> </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I got it worked thanks. https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/234