# How do I use Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter in SSMS v20?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, formatting, ssms, formatter

On installing SQL Server Management Studio v20, the menu items for Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter are gone.

[image]

Things worked fine in v18 after following the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72996345/4830285
Not so in v20.

How do I use the tool in SQL Server Management Studio v20?

Comment: This sounds like you should be reaching out the developer for support. Though SSMS 20 has only been out for a week or so, so it is more likely it's not supported (yet).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working this way.

Install SSMS 17.9.1

Install SSMS 20.x

Install PoorMansTSqlFormatter

copy PoorMansTSqlFormatterSSMSPackage.pkgdef to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 20\Extensions (located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17\Extensions or C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions)

Re-open SSMS 20.x and it should appear under Tools. (you can now fix the shortcut keys CTRL-K CTRL-D)

Uninstall SSMS 17.9.1

https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/283#issuecomment-1493274817